# how to connect zend_Db in one file

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

when i want to connect database in zend framework with zend_Db, in each controller or model must write this code:

```
$params = array(
'host'           => '127.0.0.1',
'username'       => 'webuser',
'password'       => 'xxxxxxxx',
'dbname'         => 'test',
'charset'        => 'utf8'
);
```

but when use Doctrine it's enough to write this code in application.ini

```
doctrine.dsn = "mysql://user:pass@localhost/dbase"
```

how i can use zend_Db with out set connection setting in each file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open

```
application/configs/application.ini
```

add following lines

```
resources.db.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
resources.db.isDefaultAdapter = true
resources.db.params.host = localhost
resources.db.params.username = root
resources.db.params.password = 
resources.db.params.dbname = foo
```

and then inside your Bootstrap.php

do

```
public function _initSetup()
{
$this->bootstrap('db');
}
```

and then whereever or whenever you need db instance simply do

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
```

Comment: I don't think the bootstrap code is required here. AFAIK the db resource is bootstrapped by default. At least I've never had to do that in any of my projects.

Comment: since I have mention "where-ever or whenever " which includes Bootstrap without doing it you cannot use Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter(); inside bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways one by using your configuration.ini file
by this code :

```
resources.db.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
resources.db.params.host = localhost
resources.db.params.username = root
resources.db.params.password = ''
resources.db.params.dbname = dbname
resources.db.params.driver_options.1002 = "SET NAMES utf8;"
```

or by using hte adapter class

```
$db = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql(array(
    'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'webuser',
    'password' => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'dbname'   => 'test'
));
```

and dont put any function in your bootstrap.php file